# Find two points on the sides of a triangle equidistance to the circumcenter where these three points are colinear

Tags: geometry

Given that $A$ is the center of a circle with radius $r$, and $C, D, E$ are points on the circle.

From the above, how can I locate (through construction or calculation) the points $G$ and $H$ such that $G$ is on $CD$ and $H$ is on $CE$ and $G, A, H$ are colinear and $GA=AH$?

What I know:

1. From Apollonius's Theorem, $CG^2+CH^2=2(r^2+GA^2)$
2. $CG\times GD=CH \times HE$
3. drawing figures with geogebra and by dragging the points around, I think there is a unique solution.

Comment: Rotate the triangle 180 degrees about the center of the circle and inspect the intersection points of the rotated triangle and the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As shown in figure , draw diameter FK of circle parallel with CD. Mirror CD about FK. segment C'D' is the mirror of CD and it intersects CE at H. The mirror of H about A is G and is on CD, that is , connect H to A and exrend it to meet CD at H.

Comment: Such a big mistake. I edited my answer.

Comment: $G$ is only the mirror of $H$ about $FK$ when $HA\perp FK$. This is not generally the case. Suggested edit to image: move $E$ closer to $C'$ then draw $HG$ through $A$ to intersect $CD$ at $G$.

Comment: @DanielMathias, thank you for showing my errors. This is definitely a creative point of you.